# Left-shifting an uint64_t zeroes out most significant dword

Tags: c, 64-bit, x86-64, bit-shift, stdint

The title sums it up: left-shifting an uint64_t doesn't output the expected value, and I'd like to know why. What I get is the expected result with its 4 most significant bytes zeroed out.
I'm using an x86_64 CPU (Intel i7 3770k), on Debian Jessie 64bit. This is a test program that reproduces the same behavior.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(int argc, char * * argv)
{
    uint64_t var = 0xDEFEC8ED;

    printf("%016x\n", var << 24);

    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

`00defec8ed000000 // expected
00000000ed000000 // obtained`

Comment: Many compilers with their warnings fully enabled will report the problem.  Save time, enable all compiler warnings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is `uint64_t` and you need a different type for the `printf`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(int argc, char * * argv)
{
    uint64_t var = 0xDEFEC8ED;

    printf("%016llx\n", (unsigned long long)(var << 24));

    return 0;
}
```

Which is not fully correct because there are special macros for printing those types since C99:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(int argc, char * * argv)
{
    uint64_t var = 0xDEFEC8ED;

    printf("%016" PRIX64 "\n", var << 24);

    return 0;
}
```

But you may or may not have them.

Comment: Thanks, it works, and accepted for having mentioned those special macros I didn't know about.

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
printf("%016x\n", var << 24);
```

with:

```
printf("%016llx\n", (var << 24));
```

Also, is it uint_64 or uint64_t ?